# Android async task frame animation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation

To begin with I have tried a lot of ways to make a smooth animation in Android and probably my best option was to use **AnimationDrawable**. Everything was perfect until I got out of memory exception on older devices. The reason for that obviously is the number of frames, in my case 75. That is how I got to the point of using **AsyncTask** and **Thread.sleep()** to animate the frames. To avoid animation lag I used a **Stack** in which I preload the first 10 frames and then just pop the used one and push a new one until there are no more frames. Everything worked better than I expected, but the only problem is that at the end of the animation the last frame disappears and I am hitting my head whole day to understand why is that happening with no success obviously. Below is the code from the Activity in which I call the animation and the file where the animation code is.

**SplashActivity.java**

```
private void startAnimation() {
        gifImageView = (LogoAnimImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);
        gifImageView.setSplashActivityContext(this);
        gifImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_frame_0);
        gifImageView.setAnimImageViewListener(new LogoAnimImageView.LogoAnimImageViewInterface() {
            @Override
            public void animationEnd() {
                mAnimationFinished = true;
                LoadNextActivity();

            }
        });
        gifImageView.startLogoAnimation();

    }
```

**LogoAnimImageView.java**

```
public class LogoAnimImageView extends ImageView {

    public interface LogoAnimImageViewInterface {
        void animationEnd();
    }

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Stack<Drawable> mImageStack;

    private SplashActivity mSplashActivity;

    private LogoAnimImageViewInterface mListener;

    private int mFrameIndex;

    private int[] mResources = {R.drawable.logo_frame_0,R.drawable.logo_frame_1,R.drawable.logo_frame_2,R.drawable.logo_frame_3,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_4,R.drawable.logo_frame_5,R.drawable.logo_frame_6,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_7,R.drawable.logo_frame_8,R.drawable.logo_frame_9,R.drawable.logo_frame_10,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_11,R.drawable.logo_frame_12,R.drawable.logo_frame_13,R.drawable.logo_frame_14,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_15,R.drawable.logo_frame_16,R.drawable.logo_frame_17,R.drawable.logo_frame_18,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_19,R.drawable.logo_frame_20,R.drawable.logo_frame_21,R.drawable.logo_frame_22,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_23,R.drawable.logo_frame_24,R.drawable.logo_frame_25,R.drawable.logo_frame_26,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_27,R.drawable.logo_frame_28,R.drawable.logo_frame_29,R.drawable.logo_frame_30,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_31,R.drawable.logo_frame_32,R.drawable.logo_frame_33,R.drawable.logo_frame_34,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_35,R.drawable.logo_frame_36,R.drawable.logo_frame_37,R.drawable.logo_frame_38,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_39,R.drawable.logo_frame_40,R.drawable.logo_frame_41,R.drawable.logo_frame_42,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_43,R.drawable.logo_frame_44,R.drawable.logo_frame_45,R.drawable.logo_frame_46,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_47,R.drawable.logo_frame_48,R.drawable.logo_frame_49,R.drawable.logo_frame_50,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_51,R.drawable.logo_frame_52,R.drawable.logo_frame_53,R.drawable.logo_frame_54,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_55,R.drawable.logo_frame_56,R.drawable.logo_frame_57,R.drawable.logo_frame_58,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_59,R.drawable.logo_frame_60,R.drawable.logo_frame_61,R.drawable.logo_frame_62,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_63,R.drawable.logo_frame_64,R.drawable.logo_frame_65,R.drawable.logo_frame_66,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_67,R.drawable.logo_frame_68,R.drawable.logo_frame_69,R.drawable.logo_frame_70,
            R.drawable.logo_frame_71,R.drawable.logo_frame_72,R.drawable.logo_frame_73,R.drawable.logo_frame_74

    };

    public LogoAnimImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LogoAnimImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LogoAnimImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void startLogoAnimation() {

        mFrameIndex = 10;
        mImageStack = new Stack<Drawable>();
        for (int i=1;i<=mFrameIndex;i++) {
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable(mResources[i]);
            mImageStack.push(drawable);
        }
        mFrameIndex++;
        mSplashActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LogoAnimOperation().execute((Object)null);
            }
        });



    }

    public void setSplashActivityContext(SplashActivity splashActivity) {
        this.mSplashActivity = splashActivity;
    }

    public void setAnimImageViewListener(LogoAnimImageViewInterface listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    private Drawable getDrawable(int id) {
        Drawable drawable;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            drawable = mSplashActivity.getDrawable(id);
        } else {
            drawable = mSplashActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id);
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    private class LogoAnimOperation extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            int number=1;
            while (mImageStack.size() > 1) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final Drawable drawable = mImageStack.pop();
                mSplashActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            LogoAnimImageView.this.setBackground(drawable);
                        }
                        else {
                            LogoAnimImageView.this.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                        }
                        if (mFrameIndex < mResources.length) {
                            Drawable newDrawable = getDrawable(mResources[mFrameIndex]);
                            mImageStack.push(newDrawable);
                            mFrameIndex++;
                        }

                    }
                });

            }

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            mSplashActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_frame_74);
                    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        LogoAnimImageView.this.setBackground(drawable);
                    }
                    else {
                        LogoAnimImageView.this.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                }
            });
            mListener.animationEnd();
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but the only problem is that at the end of the animation the last
>   frame disappears and I am hitting my head whole day to understand why
>   is that happening with no success obviously.

The problem may lie in your `AsyncTask's` `onPostExecute(String)`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    mSplashActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_frame_74);
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                LogoAnimImageView.this.setBackground(drawable);
            } else {
                LogoAnimImageView.this.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            }
        }
    });
    mListener.animationEnd();
    super.onPostExecute(s);
}
```

1. `onPostExecute(String)` will always be called on the UI thread. So, `mSplashActivity.runOnUiThread(....)` is redundant.
2. By using `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`, you are posting to the UI thread's event queue. So, the runnable is executed when its turn comes up. However, the code after the `mSplashActivity.runOnUiThread(....)` call *may get executed before the runnable*. So, `mListener.animationEnd()` may be getting called before your `LogoAnimImageView` has a chance to display `R.drawable.logo_frame_74`.

But, this should not happen in your case. If `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` is called from the UI thread (which, it is), the `Runnable` is *not* posted to the event queue, and executed immediately instead.

I suspect that the real issue here is that there isn't any delay between the last frame of your animation `(R.drawable.logo_frame_74)`, and launch of next activity. Perhaps you could comment out the call to `mListener.animationEnd()`, to check whether the animation ends at the last or second-last frame.

Although this is an interesting approach, and one I haven't seen before, I have to say that you are meddling with more threads than you need to. If you're trying to load `Drawables` as and when they are needed, there is a simpler way:

```
public class LogoAnimImageView extends ImageView {

    ....
    ....

    // flag to indicate whether `mNextFrameDrawable` should continue loading the next frame
    private boolean mStopAnimating;

    // loads the next frame, and calls back to activity when done
    private Runnable mNextFrameRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!mStopAnimating) {
                if (isFinishedAnimating() && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.animationEnd();
                } else { // Load next frame
                    setViewBg(getNextFrameDrawable());
                    // Will load the next frame in 40 ms
                    postDelayed(this, 40L);
                }
            }
        }
    };    

    // This method can be set `public static` and placed in a separate `Utils` class
    private void setViewBg(Drawable d) {
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            setBackground(drawable);
        } else {
            setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }   

    private Boolean isFinishedAnimating() {
        return mFrameIndex >= mResources.length; 
    } 

    // returns the next frame's drawable and increments the `mFrameIndex` pointer
    private Drawable getNextFrameDrawable() {
        return getDrawable(mResources[mFrameIndex++]);
    }

    // start animating
    public void startLogoAnimation() {
        mFrameIndex = 0;
        mStopAnimating = false;
        post(mNextFrameRunnable);
    }

    // stop animating
    public void stopLogoAnimation() {
        mStopAnimating = true;
        removeCallbacks(mNextFrameRunnable);
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

`AsyncTask` is neither needed, nor designed to handle such scenarios.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works good. The only problem is that the animation is not really smooth. Do you think that using a stack with preloaded drawables can help in increasing the performance of the animation?

Comment: @axel Sorry, I've been busy wrapping up a project. I hadn't logged in since. To make this smooth, we will need to transition from one frame to the next. Instead of calling `setViewBg(getNextFrameDrawable());
` inside `mNextFrameRunnable`, we can use a `TransitionDrawable` with a duration of say 35 ms to make this smooth. I really hope that you were able to tap some other resource to get an answer to this. If not, I can update the answer with the transition bit added.